# Google Artifact Registry: how to provide a package description

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I have created a Python package and uploaded it to GCP artifact registry:

[image: Screenshot of Python package uploaded to GCP]

I have provided a `README.md`, a description in the `pyproject.toml`, and a docstring at the packages `__init__.py` top level. **Yet, as you can see above, there is no description.**  I cannot figure out how to provide a description via any documentation within GCP's artifact registry.  Does anyone know how I can populate that *description* of a package that is in the artifact registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately right now there is no option to populate the description of a package that is in the artifact registry. And there exists a feature request for the same in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/232434109), you can either add your concern there or create a new issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/).  You can use [this page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) for reference when creating an issue.

Comment: Thanks!  I added my concern on the first link. :)